# Modal component - onClick event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to test the following click event: Using Jest and Enzyme for ReactJS

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.descriptionModalOpen} style={descriptionModalStyle}>
  <div>
   <div className='fullmodal'>
   <div className="fullmodal_title">
     <div className="fullmodal_title_add">Description</div>
   </div>             
   <div className='sidemodal_addnew_x' id="close-Modal-id" onClick={this.closeModal}>
     <FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' />
    </div>
    </div>    
   {this.getDescription()}
      </div>
    </Modal>
```

Node cannot be found. The others click events test passed just fine, but this is the only one inside of a Modal.

Here is part of my  test file

```
 beforeEach(() => (wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><Notifications {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>)));

it("should check  button click events under  Modal Component", () => {
baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
wrapper.find('Notifications').setState({
  descriptionModalOpen: false,

});
wrapper.update() 
wrapper.find('Notifications').find('#close-Modal-id').simulate("click"); 
});
```

Comment: whats the error? what is the `this.closeModal` ?

Comment: what happens if you set `descriptionModalOpen` to true ?

Comment: if I set it to true - same error : node can't be found

Comment: closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      descriptionModalOpen: false
    })
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try findWhere?

```
const yourElement = element.findWhere(node => node.id === "close-Modal-id")
yourElement.simulate('click');
```

If it doesn't, can you verify if `findWhere` traverses the node you're targeting?

Comment: wrapper.findWhere(node => node.id === "close-Modal-id") the test passes

Comment: @usertestREACT great :)

Comment: I'm running a test coverage command right now, still new to testing. I will let you know if the coverage changes

Comment: The coverage did not change, especially on  closeModal = () => { this.setState({ descriptionModalOpen: false }) }

Comment: are you allowed to add after (node => node.id === "close-Modal-id").simulate("click"). , I don't think so

Comment: @usertestREACT test if your state has changed after running simulate('click')

Comment: wrapper.findWhere(node => node.id === "close-Modal-id").simulate("click") doesn't work

Comment: @usertestREACT can you check if you actually found your node, using findWhere?

Comment: sorry , actually I just changed what is inside of node.id === "close-Modal-id", and the test passed. So there is something wrong with my set state  or node not being found.